# passing parameter value to pyspark withcolumn statement

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
dm_df = dm_df.withColumn('{}',md5(dm_df['{}']).format(impacted_columns)`)
```

I am trying to pass parameter value to pyspark withcolumn statement, but getting error as

```
u'Cannot resolve column name "{}" among
```

this statement is working fine.

```
dm_df=sqlContext.sql("""select * from dbname.{}""".format(table_name))
```

Comment: format needs to immediately follow the string, just like it does in your second example.  However, why aren't you using `fstrings`?

Comment: Can you help how to use fstrings here                                            dm_df=sqlContext.sql("""select * from dbname.{}""".format(table_name))

Comment: @AravindSundaravadivelu `(f"select * from dbname.{table_name}")`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the .format() method wrong in the following statement.
Instead of

```
dm_df = dm_df.withColumn('{}',md5(dm_df['{}']).format(impacted_columns)`)
```

try with the following

```
dm_df = dm_df.withColumn('{}',md5(dm_df[impacted_columns])`)
```

The error you are facing occurs because the spark is looking at the following literal `{}` as column name which is not available.